# Using Expression Class With LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I was wondering if there's a way to use Expression class for custom queries with LINQ queries such as this

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = (x) => x.Id = 1

var items = from item in context.TEntity
where expression
select item
```

I know there's a way to do this using LINQ function as the Where function takes an expression as a parameter but I really need to do this using LINQ queries

note: the code above is just an example to make you get around what I'm trying to do it's not an actual working code

note 2: I need this to work with Entity Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework does not natively support this type of expression projection, which is why a common attempt such as `where expression.Compile().Invoke(item);` will throw an exception at runtime.

However, if you use the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library (which utilizes the Expression Visitor) and call `.AsExpandable()` on the entity set, you can then invoke your expression dynamically:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = x => x.Id == 1;

var items = from item in context.Set<TEntity>.AsExpandable()
where expression.Invoke(item)
select item;
```

Comment: Whoops you are correct.  That Invoke is an extension method from Linqkit that works in conjunction with AsExpandable.

Comment: @DavidL, ahh, makes sense now. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy No problem, thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 1):

This works, at least on EF Core (I have just tested it). Don't have any EF6 project handy where I could test.

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = (x) => x.Id = 1

var items = from item in context.TEntity
where expression.Compile()(item);
select item
```

***Update:*** I just made a simple test project on EF6 and it does not work there, since it doesn't recognize the expression invocation

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised it worked on EF Core... I have to check if it's doing local filtering (which I heard was planned to be supported) or actually converting to SQL, but I have no time for that right now.

Comment: It does indeed local filtering. So they eliminated the runtime exception, but you have to turn on logging and check every query if you want to be sure it is performed at the db side.

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah, that was my guess... I tried enabling logging but there doesn't seem to be a consistent way to do it and I didn't have much time to test it (they changed it 3 times in 3 different versions, and the last method I found on a github issue didn't work with the published nuget packages)

Comment: @Jcl very interesting...shame it doesn't support proper projection.  However, it DOES look like they've begun the ExpressionVisitor pattern for RowNumber.  Perhaps they'll expand it out for multiple types of common expressions.